# Wordpress set Access-Control-Allow-Origin for all files in /wp-content/themes

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm having a lot of problems with CORS errors. So I want to set `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")` for everything in my WordPress `wp-content/themes` directory.

I tried to add it to the `.htaccess` in `/var/www/html` but this isn't working in `/wp-content`

Anyone has an idea on how to do this in a WordPress install?

EDIT:
It's a self-hosted ubuntu 14.04 server.
And the problem arises with static files, so I cannot add the access control to the header function.

EDIT2:

I think I didn't explain the situation correct.

I have a page on my Wordpress site [get10things.com](https://get10things.com/blog) this site uses scripts which loads resources from the same domain. However I want to show parts of this site in iframes on other domains and in our Android and iOS app. Therefor I need to enable "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" on all resources which are loaded in the scripts which are used on get10things.com.

Comment: What server are you using? Are you running the WP install locally? Is it hosted? What is the server that you are using?

Comment: Add to template header.php if exist  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")

Comment: or try add to functions.php

Comment: @Breakermind I edit my question, adding it to the header.php doesn't matter for javascript files.

Comment: You don't understand for what allow orgin is.

Comment: It allows you to connect from another server and domain from js/jquery function .post, .get  and send requests to php files. (Default js access to external servers is blocked from web browser.)

Comment: @Breakermind I made another edit to my question to explain the issue better. I might have been unclear but I do understand allow origin, but  only with this Wordpress server I'm unable to fix it.

Comment: "However I want to show parts of this site in iframes on other domains and in our Android and iOS app. Therefor I need to enable "`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`" — `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` effects the ability to read the content across origins with **JavaScript**, you need `X-Frame-Options`  … but that *defaults* to a **permissive** state.

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/

Comment: http://javascript.info/tutorial/clickjacking

Comment: document.domain = 'example.com' look at this: http://madskristensen.net/post/iframe-cross-domain-javascript-calls

Comment: a to jak znasz języki :D http://blog.kamilbrenk.pl/cross-domain-javascript/ i tutaj http://blog.kamilbrenk.pl/bezpieczne-naglowki-http/